How to Create an Inner Shadow Effect Similar to box-shadow: inset in React Native?
I'm new to React Native and using Expo to build a mobile app. I'm trying to create a design with an inner background shadow effect that makes it appear curved, similar to how I'd achieve it on the web with CSS like this:
box-shadow: inset 1px -3px 6px #63A1DE47, 0px 3px 33px #FFFFFF9C;

I've tried several libraries, such as react-native-svg and react-native-shadow-2, but none of them have provided the desired effect.
Is there a way to achieve a similar inset shadow effect in React Native? If so, what techniques or libraries should I consider?
expected design:

I've tried several libraries, such as react-native-svg and react-native-shadow-2, but none of them have provided the desired effect.

Recently released React Native 0.76 (finally) has a boxShadow property.
Although at  the moment it still has no info in View 'style' docs, you can see how it works here: 0.76 Changelog
